# Number of Downloads in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I've had an app published on Google Play for a few months.  I can see from the developer console that it's had a few downloads, but the number of downloads isn't shown beside the app icon on the app page (as it is for all other apps).

Why is this?  Do I need to configure something I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'but the number of downloads isn't printed beside the app icon'?

Comment: A screenshot of the problem would clarify what you are trying to explain.

Comment: I didn't have to do anything for mine, it appeared automatically.

Comment: Same here, I think it might be the cache.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

The Google Play Store shows (updated once a day) the number of downloads and device installations. The number you see on Google Play (in web or on their mobile app) is only updated in the following steps:

**Downloads in Google Play App**  (*Downloads in Web*)

- **1+**     (*1 - 5*)
- **5+**     (*6 - 10*)
- **10+**    (*11 - 50*)
- **50+**    (*51 - 100*)
- **100+**   (*101 - 500*)
- **500+**   (*501 - 1,000*)
- **1K+**  (*1,001 - 5,000*)
- **5K+**  (*5,001 - 10,000*)
- **10K+**  (*10,001 - 50,000*)
- **50K+**  (*50,001 - 100,000*)
- **100K+** (*100,001 - 500,000*)
- **500K+** (*500,001 - 1,000,000*)
- **1M+** (*1,000,001 - 5,000,000*)
- **5M+** (*5,000,001 - 10,000,000*)
- **10M+** (*10,000,001 - 50,000,000*)
- **50M+** (*50,000,001 - 100,000,000*)
- **100M+** (*100,000,001 - 500,000,000*)
- **500M+** (*500,000,001 - 1,000,000,000*)
- **1B+** (*1,000,000,001 - 5,000,000,000*)
- **5B+** (*5,000,000,001 - 10,000,000,000*)
- **10B+** (*10,000,000,001 - 50,000,000,000*)

So, if your app isn't downloaded often, it will take days or weeks to reach the next level.

Comment: To add to it the play store page is updated daily so the numbers wont be updated in real time.

Comment: Is the number of downloads computed based on lifetime numbers ? My app (Match4app) shows 5.10 K "Installs by User" on Google Play Console. However, on Google Play Store it only shows 1000+.

Comment: My app has 'Installs by user' =10,22К for lifetime period. And badge not updated in Gplay yet from 5k+ to 10k+ for a one month now. Why is that? What I need to do?

Comment: To update this for 2019, it seems instant apps may be included in this total, as I have a 10+ installs for my still undiscovered paid game app even though no one has actually purchased the full installation version. This could also be pirated installs, however. Would be nice to know for sure on this.

Comment: It has been over a month and my install count is still not updated. Google......

Comment: @hb it changed now? Do you already check if the reach the next level? In the Google Play Console you should see real downloads stats day by day..

Comment: @HB. I have the same issue with [Coinverse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.coinverse). This past week I reached a new install bracket based on the [play.google.com/console](https://play.google.com/console) dashboard. However, 24-48 hrs later, the Play Store is showing the lower bracket range of installs. How long did it take for the Play Store to update for you?

Comment: @adamHurwitz It depends which stats are you looking at, there are 2 different downlaod stats, users stats and devices stats. For example if the same user download once in his phone and tablet, then the user stats will be increased by one, and the device stats will be increased by 2.
More info [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: @HB., thank you for clarifying! I'm referring to 'New users acquired' stats shown under the 'Dashboard' on the Play console desktop view. The lifetime 'New users acquired' stats  shown are above the install bracket. However, the number has not updated on the [Google Play listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.coinverse).

Comment: It updates more than once a day. The corona app in my country was published today and the installation number updated multiple times (from 100k+, to 500k+, to 1M+) today

Comment: Any reference, please

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation from which you took that form?

Comment: I found for my apps the total downloads via the playstore on the PC showed all the above badges, but via the mobile play store app i only saw badges once they were at 100+.

Comment: Locale changes the string, I followed a link to:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skillsoft.Percipio&hl=en_IN The en_IN setting is still English, but the _IN meant that 500K+
Downloads got rendered as 5L+
Downloads because it is measured in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Comment: They somewhere stated that the "New users aquired" is not the same as the installations shown in Google Play. That's probably to prevent fraud. If you buy some cheap installs only to increase the number you may see them in your console as actual installs, but Google Play won't show them publicly. This way it's harder for people to find out how Google Play detects fraudulent installs. Google Play probably also counts some installs as fraudulent for a legit app if someone just installs the app and immediately uninstalls it again without launching it etc.

Comment: What does T denotes, I think its India specific , as obvious but doesn't look its for Trillion as I see some apps like "Radio India FM - All India" has 3T , pls suggest

Answer (score 49):

As Tano pointed out the number of downloads are just given in categories. These categories are (as of december 2015):

- 1 - 5
- 5 - 10
- 10 - 50
- 50 - 100
- 100 - 500
- 500 - 1.000
- 1.000 - 5.000
- 5.000 - 10.000
- 10.000 - 50.000
- 50.000 - 100.000
- 100.000 - 500.000
- 500.000 - 1.000.000
- 1.000.000 - 5.000.000
- 5.000.000 - 10.000.000
- 10.000.000 - 50.000.000
- 50.000.000 - 100.000.000
- 100.000.000 - 500.000.000
- 500.000.000 - 1.000.000.000
- 1.000.000.000 - 5.000.000.000

Comment: But for me No of downloads are not showing 

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=myoracle.com.quotes

How can i enable it

Comment: Do you have a source for this, or did you just figure it out?

Comment: I looked through apps in the store and noted the categories. I found apps for each of these categories.

Answer (score 30):

Google Play does not update 'Download Badge' immediately. In order to see the unique install count of your app, go to Google Play console > Dashboard page > **New users acquired** (Select 'Lifetime' from top-right dropdown instead of last 30 days). This number should not be recognized as a sole number for a download count badge.

Google Play presents download badges based on "Total User Installs (total number of unique users who have ever installed this app on one or more of their devices)". Although my app exceeded 100 K New users acquired, Google Play application page shows 50 K+ installs. I opened a ticket about it since I had not found exact info about it. They replied as the number of downloads that contribute to gain a new download badge is not exactly the same with  'New users acquired'. The threshold count is Google Play's internal information and in some cases, install metrics may be discounted or removed entirely if they detect fraudulent installs.

The download range (2020) is like below:
K(Thousand) , M( Million) , B( Billion)

- 1 +
- 5 +
- 10 +
- 50 +
- 100 +
- 500 +
- 1 K +
- 5 K +
- 10 K +
- 50 K +
- 100 K +
- 500 K +
- 1 M +
- 5 M +
- 10 M +
- 50 M +
- 100 M +
- 500 M +
- 1 B +
- 5 B +

K(Thousand) , M( Million) , B( Billion)

Comment: What does 5T+ download means?

Comment: T stands for thousand, so 5T+ would be 5000+

Comment: This is because people uninstall the app. The larger number includes people that installed it then uninstalled it later

Comment: now what does 10L and 10Cr mean? Chrome has 1TCr downloads

Answer (score 9):

This might help

1. Select your app and go to dashboard
2. Check "New users acquired"

Or

Go to Statistics and select below filters in "Configure Report"
Add a metric -> Users -> User acquisitions -> New Users

Select  time intervals monthly
 You will get results for "New user acquisitions (Unique users, Per interval, Monthly)"
Add them you will get your total downloads

Depending upon the age of the app, the updates may be delay by a few days(3-4)

Comment: how to add, one by one?

Answer (score 6):

Play store starts showing the download number beside the app icon only when download number is more than 50. Even though your app gets more than 50 downloads, it may take upto 2 days for the download number to appear on playstore

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to your respective app "dashboard"
2. Change the timeframe to lifetime
3. The "installs by user" card will show the total installs