# Total number of installs app in Google Play is still 0+ after two days

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I published my app on Google Play store since two days on and I still cannot see any number of installs in app page even though I see in Google Play console statistics there's about 31 user installed the app

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you need to wait for one day (sometimes it is slower) for the data to be updated. The total number of downloads are:

- 1+ (1 - 5);
- 5+ (6 - 10);
- 10+ (11 - 50);
- 50+ (51 - 100);
- 100+ (101 - 500);
- 500+ (501 - 1000);
- 1000+ (1001 - 5000);
- 5000+ (5001 - 10000);
- 10000+ (10001 - 50000);
- 50000+ (50001–100000);
- 100000+ (100001–500000);
- 500000+ (500001–1000000);
- 1000000+ (1000001–5000000);
- 5000000+ (5000001–10000000);
- 10000000+ (10000001–50000000);
- 50000000+ (50000001–100000000);
- 100000000+ (100000001–500000000);
- 500000000+ (500000001–1000000000);
- 1000000000+ (1000000001–5000000000).

Reference to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11537826/8594783

Additional information:

- Some information such as privacy policy's URL or developer's address is updated very fast (almost instantly, sometimes slower).
- Review and rating: after several minutes (sometimes slower)
- App's description: after half an hour or up to several hours
- App's screenshots: after half an hour or up to several hours