# How is the number of downloads computed in Google Play store?

Tags: download, google-play, google-play-console

Is the number of downloads shown in Google Play Store computed based on lifetime numbers ? My app (Match4app) shows 5.10 K "Installs by User" on Google Play Console (lifetime). However, on Google Play Store it only shows 1000+:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.palfonsoft.match4app

I know this is not real time, however I had more than 5K downloads since April 2019.

According to some documentation, it is supposed to show "5000+":

1+ (1 - 5)

5+ (6 - 10)

10+ (11 - 50)

50+ (51 - 100)

100+ (101 - 500)

500+ (501 - 1000)

1000+ (1001 - 5000)

5000+ (5001 - 10000)

10000+ (10001 - 50000)

etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of Downloads in Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487470/number-of-downloads-in-google-play)

Comment: @JuciReif In that question, user says that the download number is not even shown. My question is about the difference between the "Installs by Users" in the console (5.10K) and "number of downloads" in the store (1000+).

Answer (score 2):

Installed by User isn't the same as Download-Count. I think that the download counter only counts unique downloads. 
The download count bracket you have is right.

Answer (score 2):

"5000+ downloads" is finally shown for Match4App in Google Play!
I had to wait for more than one month though. 
This is more likely a sync issue between the Google Play Console and the Playstore, because now I have 10000+ in the Console :)

Answer (score -2):

The Google Play app download brackets are

```
0
1-5
5-10
10-50
50-100
100-500
500-1000
1000-5000
5000 - 10000
10000 - 50000
50000 - 100000
100000 - 500000
500000 - 1000000
1000000 - 5000000
5000000 - 10000000
10000000 - 50000000
50000000 - 100000000
100000000 - 500000000
500000000 - 1000000000
1000000000 - 5000000000
```

Answer from [quora](https://www.quora.com/Google-Play-publishes-the-amount-of-downloads-an-app-has-in-incremental-brackets-i-e-100-500-10-000-000-50-000-000-Where-can-I-find-a-full-list-of-the-range-of-brackets/answer/Pratik-Butani).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question where the measurement is based upon.