# How are downloads counted in the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

How are the download numbers publicly displayed in the Google Play Store for each app counted? Which of the options is correct?

1. Each download is counted (regardless of whether the app has been downloaded before by the user or the device) (unlikely, otherwise you could manipulate the numbers).
2. Downloads are only counted once for each device.
3. Downloads are only counted once for each user.

Many thanks in advance!

Example:
[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487470/number-of-downloads-in-google-play

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for your comment! Should I delete the question?

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah: Thanks for your comment! Maybe. This would support option 3.